# How to get the GRUB menu back on Debian

Tags: debian, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I recently installed Debian stable and now after boot I get a grub command line instead of the usual menu. When I run `configfile (hd0,gpt6)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, I get to the grub menu and see that Debian as well as Widnows are listed there, so grub seems to be installed correctly. I know that there many questions around this already, so here is what I have tried already to solve the issue:

- Boot into a boot-repair-disk and run recommended repair from there
- Manually mount the system from a live disk `chroot` into it and install grub
- Following [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux), I ran `update-grub` and `install-grub /dev/sda`
- Also tried `grub-mkdevicemap`, `grub-install /dev/sda`, and then `update-grub`

None of this worked, I still get the grub prompt after booting.

I have a dual boot setup with Windows on another partition. Secure boot is disabled. Before I installed Debian on this partition I had another distro installed on it and the grub menu worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I seems like the boot manager was still loading the Ubuntu grub and the Debian grub was not included. I just has to execute `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\debian\grubx64.efi` from Windows PowerShell.